# How to respond to "NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default." from system upgrade

Tags: linux, php, debian, apache2, update

I did a standard OS update on Ubuntu LTS (20.04) and the messages end with:

```
Processing triggers for php7.4-fpm (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.6) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
```

Yes, I am using Apache2. How do I decide whether I want to run those commands to enable PHP 7.4?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP-fpm you run
`a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif` and
`a2enconf php7.4-fpm`

If you are asking why you should install it, it is better to install it if you want to have less overload on your system, have extra security, and want to configure every aspect of PHP. I use it on my website and it works very well!
I would suggest installing it.